# How to get database to read form value, not option number

Tags: ruby-on-rails, best-in-place

For my profile fields such as Ethnicity. User 1 has selected 'Asian' as their ethnicity. In the Users database it will show numbers for the selected Ethnicity (such as Asian = 1, Dutch = 2, etc based on the order of ethnicities from the options list) and the Search database only recognizes the ethnicity itself...not the number for the ethnicity. So the Search is trying to find users with Asian selected, but technically there are none since the User database goes by a number instead of the name of the ethnicity.

I believe my User database is showing numbers because that is what's used in the form with the best_in_place gem.

show.html:

```
 <p>Ethnicity: <%= best_in_place @user, :ethnicity, nil: 'What is your ethnicity?', :type => :select, :collection => [[1, "Asian"], [2, "Biracial"], [3, "Indian"], [4, "Hispanic/Latin"], [5, "Middle Eastern"], [6, "Native American"], [7, "Pacific Islander"], [8, "White"], [9, "Other"]] %></p>
```

I have tried doing:

```
collection: ["Asian", "Biracial", "Indian"]
```

and

```
collection: [ ["Asian", "Asian"], ["Biracial", "Biracial"], ["Indian", "Indian"]]
```

If I do the first example the option that should read 'Asian' will instead read "s".

The second example doesn't display any option, so it's just a blank drop down box.

Does anyone know how I can get these options to save to User database as the actual option as oppose to the numbers?

schema:

```
 create_table "searches", :force => true do |t|
    t.string   "gender"
    t.string   "age"
    t.string   "zip_code"
    t.string   "children"
    t.string   "religion"
    t.string   "ethnicity"
    t.datetime "created_at", :null => false
    t.datetime "updated_at", :null => false
  end

  create_table "users", :force => true do |t|
    t.string   "email"
    t.string   "password_digest"
    t.string   "zip_code"
    t.string   "birthday"
    t.string   "name"
    t.string   "username"
    t.string   "gender"
    t.string   "ethnicity"
    t.string   "sexuality"
    t.string   "career"
    t.string   "education"
    t.string   "religion"
    t.string   "politics"
    t.string   "children"
    t.string   "height"
    t.string   "user_smoke"
    t.string   "user_drink"
    t.string   "about_me"
    t.string   "inches"
    t.string   "feet"
    t.datetime "created_at",             :null => false
    t.datetime "updated_at",             :null => false
    t.string   "auth_token"
    t.string   "password_reset_token"
    t.datetime "password_reset_sent_at"
    t.boolean  "admin"
    t.string   "role"
    t.integer  "roles_mask"
    t.string   "age"
    t.string   "age_end"
  end
```

Comment: How are you storing the ethnicity in the database? What is the column type? Can you post the relevant parts of your db/schema.rb?

Comment: I added schema. All of them are strings and stored as the name. It's grabbing the numbers from my form on show.html. But I have to use that the best in place gem.

Answer (score 0):

I figured the problem out. The best in place code was fine, I just needed to modify the search form.

```
<%= f.select :ethnicity, [["Asian", "1"], ["Biracial", "2"], ["Indian", "3"], ["Hispanic/Latin", "4"], ["Middle Eastern", "5"], ["Native American", "6"], ["Pacific Islander", "7"], ["White", "8"], ["Other", "9"]], :include_blank => true %>
```

As you can see I added the value as it's showing in my database after the name of the ethnicity. This now pulls searches up perfectly.